# how to play m3u8 with exoplayer, the screen remains black

Tags: android, m3u8, exoplayer2.x

goes black trying to play m3u8 with exoplayer v2.10.5,which makes me add or how can I play m3u with exoplayer v2.10.5 and gradle 3.5.3 
or which version of exoplayer would work with api 28 and gradle 3.5.3

if you can help me accommodate the code or explain it, much better I'm starting on this and it would be a help, the mp4 plays without problem.

````
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


/**
 * A fullscreen activity to play audio or video streams.
 */
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private PlayerView playerView;
  private SimpleExoPlayer player;
  private boolean playWhenReady=true;
  private long playbackPosition=0;
  private int currentWindow=0;
  public String urlStream;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    urlStream = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("URL");

    playerView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (Util.SDK_INT < 24) {
      releasePlayer();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (Util.SDK_INT >= 24) {
      releasePlayer();
    }
  }

  private void releasePlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
      playWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
      playbackPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
      currentWindow = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
      player.release();
      player = null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (Util.SDK_INT >= 24) {
      initializePlayer();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    hideSystemUi();
    if ((Util.SDK_INT < 24 || player == null)) {
      initializePlayer();
    }
  }

  @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
  private void hideSystemUi() {
    playerView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
  }

  private void initializePlayer() {


    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
    playerView.setPlayer(player);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlStream);
    MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);

    player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
    player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
    player.prepare(mediaSource, false, false);
  }

  private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
            new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "exoplayer-codelab");
    return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(uri);
  }


} ```
````

Comment: check if the dependency for jls format is added.
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.12.0'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use [HLS](https://exoplayer.dev/hls.html) media source to play m3u8 file.

use this

```
private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "exoplayer-codelab");
    return new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
}
```

instead of this

```
private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "exoplayer-codelab");
    return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For future readers trying to stream m3u8 formats

Add this dependency to your build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.X.X'
```

then load your m3u8 url just like loading other default formats

```
// Create a player instance.
ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();

// Set the media item to be played.
player.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(hlsUri));
// Prepare the player.
player.prepare();
```

Checkout the [Official ExoPlayer Docs](https://exoplayer.dev/hls.html) for more information.

Also be informed that ExoPlayer has became a part of the android JetPack. Visit [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer) for the official documentation.